# CSV writer cuts off some writes

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading some lines from a regular text file and appending them in a list. Every so often, this list is merged into a single-element list and written out to a CSV file. However, occasionally I see that the data written out is prematurely cut off at some arbitrary point, i.e. rest of data is missing. If I print this list to console before writing to file, I can see that all the data is clearly there, so I assume this is some formatting or IO issue in my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
with open(out_fname, 'wb') as fout:
    csv_out = csv.writer(fout)
    csv_out.writerow(header_list)

    with open(in_fname, 'rb') as fin:
        for _ in xrange(data_start_row-1):
            next(fin)

        for line in fin:
            #find identifier for row of interest
            if re.search(regex_id, line):
                #parse out first parameter
                match1 = re.search(regex_m1, line)
                if match1: csv_out_l.append(match1.group(1))
                #parse out second parameter
                match2 = re.search(regex_m2, line)
                if match2: csv_out_l.append(match2.group(1))
                #parse out third parameter
                match3 = re.search(regex_m3, line)
                if match3: csv_out_l.append(match3.group(1))
                #remove all newline elements in rest of log info
                log_info = [element for element in log_info if element != '\n']
                #remove all newline char's in elements
                log_info = map(lambda s: s.strip(), log_info)

                log_info = ["\n".join(log_info)]

                csv_out.writerow(csv_out_l + log_info)

                #clear lists
                csv_out_l[:] = []
                log_info[:] = []

                #skip next line which does not contain useful info
                next(fin)
            #otherwise store general data in the meantime
            else:
                log_info.append(line)
```

Comment: next(fin) <-- is line seems odd. 
The for line in fin loop should take you to the next line at that point anyway.

Comment: @PabTorre / @Colin: maybe `fin.next()` will work?

Comment: maybe I'm missing something. 
What happens if you just comment out that line?

Comment: I have tried to comment it out and also replace with fin.next() but it does not seem to make a difference. I have also tried putting a break after the first writerow(csv_out_l + log_info) and I can already see data missing in the file. When I print(csv_out_l + log_info) it looks fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realized that this is not a Python issue. It is related to Excel not liking the fact that some of my CSV output lines start with equal (=) sign. I suppose Excel thinks it's a formula and cuts off characters after a limit. If I add an apostrophe to the beginning, then everything works. Thanks for your feedback anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I realized that this is not a Python issue. It is related to Excel not liking the fact that some of my CSV output lines start with equal (=) sign. I suppose Excel thinks it's a formula and cuts off characters after a limit. If I add an apostrophe to the beginning, then everything works.